# PHP SESSION destroy when user close the browser or automatic session destroy

Tags: php, session, cron, onbeforeunload

I have a hole in my login-logout script and i really have no idea how to fill it. 
The whole problem appeared when users started to simply leave the page instead of logging out. There actually wouldn't be anything bad about it, because in my code there is logout after 15 minutes(session time out), but in my database there is a column "online" which is changed on login and logout, so when user just close the page it doesn't change to offline.

I was trying window.onbeforeunload to href to page where the logout is (didn't work)
I have heared also about cron but i have completly no idea how to do this.

Can anyone tell me how to solve my problem with detailed explanation?
Looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: Not possible. You cannot reliably detect when a person closes a window or tab... and how would you detect if a user has multiple tabs open on your site and closes one? Now they're logged out in ALL tabs. PHP itself will clean stale sessions anyways. You don't NEED to do anything, other than set the session lifespan - just let PHP take care of it.

Comment: I want to see people that are online and i have it in my database, how should i do it than?

Comment: Change "who is online right now" to "who did something in the last 15 minutes".

Comment: Agree with Marc B. You could potentially profile your users' last activity date and then poll for that information.  Add an "idle" state or something if folks haven't done anything in the last five minutes or so. If they haven't done anything in the amount of time it takes for their session to expire, then update UI to show them offline.

Comment: everything is held in database, so maybe i'll make in db something like expected logout time and run this script every 15 minutes? (With cron)

Comment: if they're database-based sessions, then essentially whatever records exist in the DB are the people who are "online". A proper session handler always keeps track of "last hit" time, to keep the session files refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

A solution could be that each time the page loads or perhaps an ajax request for each page to bounce a code to the server to say "hey, this user is online", and then have a built in function to your scripts (that work on any page, anyone views) to check if the mysql update time is within the last X minutes and if not the user is assumed to have logged out.

I think I've explained that quite badly.

You have a timestamp field in your Table - associated with each user logged in, and they're deemed to be online if the timestamp last update is within X minutes of NOW,

So, each time a page is loaded or each time an ajax call is processed, the timstamp field is updated, and then on any field that has timestamp older than X minutes, this is because they've (probably) logged out and so they are changed in the DB to being "offline". Although if they're just busy and still online, perhaps don't actually log them out, just mark them as offline.

I'm running without details on how you process your database content details etc., so my idea might be well out from what you can create - ?

EDIT:
Ajax Suggestion

For ajax to act on each page every X seconds, write the following ajax onto the page the member is on, be aware that the number at the end is milliseconds, 600000 = 10 minutes. So used 500000 as it's within the timescope. so the ajax function runs every 8.5 minutes, or on page load.

THe ajax is quite poorly written and probably can be improved. But should work. You'll need to research a more optimal ajax script.

BROWSER PAGE:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

     $( document ).ready(function() {
    var memberId = <?php print $memberId; ?>;
var securityKey = <?php print some security key code or suchlike to validate this ajax at the otherend;?>;

         setInterval(function(){
         $.post("/ajaxSession.php",{
                MemberId: memberId,
                somesecuritykey: securityKey
            });
        }, 500000);
    });

</script>
```

AJAX PAGE:
Please note update time in this case is a 'timestamp' MySQL field.

```
    <?php
    /**
    Setup this page as if any other PHP page but this page will never show to the browser,
    AJAX data is supplied as $_POST and inn this case $_POST['somesecuritykey'] and $_POST['MemberId'] 
    **/

session_start();
/**
include classes and files
**/
if (is_numeric($_POST['MemberId'])){
$memid= (int)$_POST['MemberId'];

/**Also include your security stuff here **/

$sql = "UPDATE Members SET UpdateTime = NOW() , LoggedIn = 'YES' WHERE MemberId = ? LIMIT 1"
$mysqli = new mysqli();
$mysqli->prepare($sql);
$mysqli->bind_param("i",$memid);
$mysqli->execute();

}
```

And that should keep the timestamp values upto date, so logged in people is anyone whose UpdateTime is MORE than time()-601 (10:01 minutes), SQL listings can change this on any header/class which occurs when anyone access any page

```
SQL = "UPDATE Members SET LoggedIn = 'NO' WHERE UpdateTime < (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)"
```

Comment: Okey, i think i have an idea. I'll run script every 15 minutes to check if user last activity was in 15 minutes. I'm using php and mysql.

Comment: So have a column named LoginTimestamp or whatever and then run the ajax every ~10 minutes or so, keep it within the max time of 15 minutes, to see if they're online and then to update the timestamp, and you have the code built into any of your construction functions to set user as offline if their timestamp < time()-900 .
Let me know if it works out!

Comment: The only issue is that it will be a bit more server traffic having this sort of update going on per user per 1 minute or something, so if you have only a small number of users and/or a large amount of free server resources having a more common ajax every 5  or 3 or 2 minutes etc. wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: But there is a problem - i don't know ajax, can you write me the code or write steps what to do?
Script runs after x minutes and what? How can i communicate with mysql using ajax? And is it going to work when user close the page?

Comment: I will write you an ajax suggestion as an edit to this answer.

Comment: Please note my Ajax and code here is poor and should be used as a STARTING POINT, not as a finished method.

Comment: I'll play with it on friday, now i don't have time. Please tell me if it will work when user close the page? If yes than okey, else i'll do that my way. I want to make sql query to update lastactivity and compare this time with actual time by using cron script which will be run every 1hour because i can't do that more often on my hosting.

Comment: I was quite tired when I wrote the ajax but it should be adequate. When the user closes the page, it will take a maximum time (in the example 500 seconds), for the system to notice the user is no longer present, so if the ajax fires and then 450 seconds later the page is closed, the user is marked as offline only 50 seconds after that. The user is marked as offline by any other script on the site, so if no one is on the site, the data isn't updated but as no one's on the site the data won't be seen anyway! Good luck with setting it up :)